# Select from 2 Tables, 2 Foreign Keys with 1 exception value | MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a sql-statement for following problem:
I got two tables:

```
**Table user**
    user_id      |  user_name
    1            |  Carl
    2            |  Claudia
    3            |  Janet
    4            |  Ben

**Table matching**
    matching_id  |    user_id_1_FK  |    user_id_2_FK
    1            |    1             |    2
    2            |    3             |    1
    3            |    4             |    2
```

**Now want to have a list of all matchings/pairs where user carl is beeing part of it**

The result should be:

```
user_name    | user_id
Claudia      | 2
Janet        | 3
```

Thx for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value-add to such a query is not very obvious to me, but after playing around a little, I came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT other_user_id, target.user_name
FROM (
    select user_id_1_FK as leading_user_id, user_id_2_FK as other_user_id
    from matching

    union all

    select user_id_2_FK as leading_user_id, user_id_1_FK as other_user_id
    from matching
) as allmatching 
LEFT JOIN user as target on allmatching.other_user_id = target.user_id
RIGHT JOIN user as source on allmatching.leading_user_id = source.user_id
WHERE source.user_name = 'Carl';
```

The trick is that, apparently, your matching table is specifying a bi-directional property: it does not matter from which side it is being read. To factor that into the query, a `UNION` operation is being used. Afterwards, it is just a matter of joining the `user` table twice to allow using "natural" terms instead of the surrogate IDs.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. To handle with the UNION operation in conjunction with joining this table... wow... that is a mental leap...

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;

CREATE TABLE user
(user_id      INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,user_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO user VALUES
(1,'Carl'),
(2,'Claudia'),
(3,'Janet'),
(4,'Ben');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS matching;

CREATE TABLE matching
(user_id1 INT NOT NULL
,user_id2 INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (user_id1,user_id2)
);

INSERT INTO matching VALUES
(1,2),
(3,1),
(4,2);

SELECT u.* 
  FROM user u 
  JOIN matching m  
    ON u.user_id IN(m.user_id1,m.user_id2) 
  JOIN user x 
    ON x.user_id IN(m.user_id1,m.user_id2) 
 WHERE x.user_name = 'Carl' 
   AND x.user_id <> u.user_id;
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       2 | Claudia   |
|       3 | Janet     |
+---------+-----------+
```